# How can I make related-object without url parameter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have some related model `Textbook`, `Chapter`, ..etc. Obviously, `Textbook` has many `Chapter` so both model has its eloquent relation method bidirectionally.

Last week, I make my route with `textbook/{textbook}/chapter/create`. In this time, I just make the route without `textbook` model. Before that, this binding makes too long and complicated.. like.. `textbook/{textbook}/chapter/{chapter}/section/{section}/item/{item}` .. so I just gave up.

After that, I tried depth-two (?) style.. like.. `textbook/{textbook}/chapter/{chapter}`, `chapter/{chapter}/section/{section}` , ... it works nicely in a short period but in many to many relation, reveals a problem that I can't find proper parent model when I needed..

How do you find proper parent model without massive-chain of url parameters?

Comment: I think my question is unclear or something..

I was thinking, when using blade, `{{Route('textbook.chapter.create', ['othervar'=>$var])}}` can pass 'othervar' variable to its Controller method.

Comment: Only problem is.. it doesn't pass variable into controller method except url related params..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say Having url params in route is one way. But you can do it other way as :

Create route `/chapter/create` as it is the standard resource crud.

And pass the textbook_id, section_id etc as hidden parameters to the controller. This makes the url cleaner for large depth in relations.

Plus `/chapter/create` is much cleaner looking url than `textbook/123/section/345/chapter/create`

So when you redirect to create route, you are currently passing textbook_id and section_id etc in url, instead pass in to blade via `->with()` and then set values of hidden inputs using that data.

Comment: Well, problem is I can't pass hidden parameter from HTML form to Controller. I was thinking, `{{Route('textbook.chapter.create, ['textbook'=>$textbook->id]}}` is enough.. but somehow it didn't..

Answer (score 0):

I do some research and the problem is solved very simple way..

When I pass non-url parameter, I can use this param via `Request` object. Somehow, even though it's not my first time passing URL params, I didn't know that I can use `Request` for this...